# MySQL. Объединить результаты двух поздапросов с третьей таблицей

Tags: mysql, join

Есть два подзапроса. Оба возвращают таблицы вида:

```
код_товара | SUM(колво_поступило)
код_товара | SUM(колво_продали)
```

которые высчитываются из разных таблиц.

Как объединить результаты этих подзапросов с таблицей `товары`:

```
код_товара | наименование_товара
```

чтобы можно было в основном запросе выбрать:

```
SELECT наименование_товара, (колво_поступило)-(колво_продали) AS осталось
FROM товары JOIN --подставить результат подзапросов
...
HAVING осталось>0
```

?

Если напрямую подзапросы подставлять в `JOIN` с таблицей `товары`, то phpMyAdmin тут же ругается на недопустимый синтаксис такого JOIN'а.

Comment: Приведите код, которым вы "напрямую подставляете подзапросы". По идее, псевдоним должен вас спасти.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `наименование_товара`, (q1.`колво_поступило`)-(q2.`колво_продали`) AS `осталось`
FROM `товары` t1
JOIN (подзапрос_1) AS q1 ON q1.`код_товара` = `t1.код_товара`
JOIN (подзапрос_2) AS q2 ON q2.`код_товара` = `t1.код_товара`
HAVING `осталось` > 0;
```